# Integration trouble on a conservative vector field

Tags: multivariable-calculus, integration, vector-analysis

I'm trying to integrate $\int_{\mathbf{x}}{\mathbf{F}\cdot{d\mathbf{s}}}$ where 
$$\mathbf{F}=x^2\mathbf{i}+\cos{y}\sin{z}\mathbf{j}+\sin{y}\cos{z}\mathbf{k}$$and $$\mathbf{x}:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3; \mathbf{x}(t)=(t^2+1,e^t,e^{2t})$$
I'm at the point where I have 
$$\int_{\mathbf{x}}{\mathbf{F}\cdot{d\mathbf{s}}}=\int_{\mathbf{x}}{x^2dx+\cos{y}\sin{z}dy+\sin{y}\cos{z}dz}$$$$=\int_0^1{(t^2+1)^22tdt+\int_0^1e^t[\cos{e^t}\sin{e^{2t}}+2e^t\cos{e^{2t}}\sin{e^t}]dt}$$
Thought I could use the $\sin{(A+B)}$ rule but the $2e^t$ is in front of the second term.  The second thought was substitution, but I can't justify both $e^t$ and $e^{2t}$ terms.  What am I missing?

EDIT:  corrected typo in vector $\mathbf{x}(t)$.  I should also point out that I'm not worried about the integral on the left.  That poses no issues....

Comment: Any reason why applying the FTC is not enough or not allowed?

Comment: no...what am i not seeing with FTC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the opportunity to use the fundamental theorem of calculus for line integrals. As the title says, the field is conservative: it is the gradient of $x^3/3+\sin y\sin z$. Evaluate the potential function at the endpoints, and you are done.

Comment: Hmmm.. I don't recall seeing that in my Vector Calculus book...I'll have to check.  So my endpoints then are evaluated at $t=0$, and $t=1$, and thus are $(1,1,1)$ and $(2,e,e^2)$?

Comment: Thanks.  I appreciate that.  Now that I see the potential function (which I had on my exercise) I can see the product rule at work in my integral.  I can see how it coalesces to the potential function.