# Quickest way to determine if a vector field is conservative?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields

Say I have some vector field given by $$\vec{F} (x,y,z)=(zy+\sin x)\hat \imath+(zx-2y)\hat\jmath+(yx-z)\hat k$$ and I need to verify that $\vec F$ is a conservative vector field. What would be the most convenient way to do this?

Indeed I managed to show that this is a vector field by simply finding an $f$ such that $\nabla f=\vec{F}$. But I'm not sure if there is a nicer/faster way of doing this.

**Side question** I found $$f(x, y, z) = xyz-y^2-\frac{z^2}{2}-\cos x,$$ so would I be correct in saying that any $f$ that shows $\vec{F}$ is conservative is of the form $$f(x, y, z) = xyz-y^2-\frac{z^2}{2}-\cos x+\varphi$$ for $\varphi \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: What you did is totally correct. A faster way would have been calculating $\operatorname{curl} F=0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A vector field $\bf G$ defined on all of $\Bbb R^3$ (or any simply connected subset thereof) is conservative iff its curl is zero $$\text{curl } {\bf G} = 0 ;$$ we call such a vector field *irrotational*. This is easier than finding an explicit potential $\varphi$ of $\bf G$ inasmuch as differentiation is easier than integration. (NB that simple connectedness of the domain of $\bf G$ really is essential here: It's not too hard to write down an irrotational vector field that is not the gradient of any function.)

The answer to your second question is yes: Given two potentials $g$ and $h$ for a vector field $\Bbb G$ on some open subset $U \subseteq \Bbb R^n$, we have
$$\nabla (h - g) = \nabla h - \nabla g = {\bf G} - {\bf G} = {\bf 0};$$
in components, this says that the partial derivatives of $h - g$ are $0$, and hence $h - g$ is constant on the connected components of $U$. In particular, if $U$ is connected, then for any potential $g$ of $\bf G$, every other potential of $\bf G$ can be written as
$$g(x, y, z) + c$$
for some constant $c$.

Comment: Ok thanks. Could you help me calculate $$\int_C \vec{F}.d\vec {r}$$ where $C$ is given by $x=y=z^2$ from $(0,0,0)$ to $(0,0,1)$?

I'm really having difficulties understanding what to do? I know the actual path doesn't matter since it is conservative but I don't know how to evaluate the integral? 

@Crostul

Comment: Take your potential function f, and then compute $f(0,0,1) - f(0,0,0)$.

Comment: Okay that is easy enough but I don't see how that works?

Comment: @Deano You're welcome. As for your integration question, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/522084/integration-trouble-on-a-conservative-vector-field?rq=1 .

Comment: According to the Fundamental Theorem of Line Integrals, the line integral of the gradient of f equals the net change of f from the initial point of the curve to the terminal point.  You found that $F$ was the gradient of $f$.  So the line integral is equal to the value of $f$ at the terminal point $(0,0,1)$ minus the value of $f$ at the initial point $(0,0,0)$

Comment: Yes I am aware of the gradient theorem, I just don't understand why it works. Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps these tutorial notes, which include the proof and a worked-out example, will help: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/FundThmLineIntegrals.aspx

Comment: Will have a bash at that later. Much obliged.

Answer (score 1):

A vector field $\textbf{A}$ on a simply connected region is conservative if and only if $\nabla \times \textbf{A} = \textbf{0}$.

Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field#Irrotational_vector_fields