# Are most vector fields conservative?

Tags: vector-fields

I started learning line integrals and vector fields, and my question is: are the majority of "nice" functions (like polynomials, trig etc) conservative?
I ask this  because of the definition:
$\vec{f}$ is conservative $\iff$ there exists a scalar field $\vec{F}$ s.t. $\nabla \vec{F} = \vec{f}$.
When equating the components to solve for $F$, it seems that almost all $\vec{f}$ can be found as the gradient of some scalar field $\vec{F}$ (assuming that we can integrate the functions of course).

Also, I see some sources verify that the curl of $f$ is zero, concluding that $f$ is conservative, but I know this shouldn't be true right? When is this true?

Comment: It's actually always true that the field is conservative if its curl is zero. This gives an easy way to test for a conservative fields higher than 2 dimensions. If you're looking at a 2 dimensional problem, it's usually just faster to take the partial derivatives and see if they match.

Comment: @Kaynex Under certain conditions ...

Comment: No, it is not always true that the field is conservative if its curl is zero. It depends on the topology of the domain. More specifically, for instance, if the domain is simply connected, then one can conclude that this is true.

Comment: Hm am I misinterpreting this then: https://math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m13w12/public_html/notes/class15.pdf  
(the very last paragraph). It states that the test does NOT determine if the field is conservative.  
@AloizioMacedo Sorry, what do you mean by "simply connected"? We've only touched on "path-connectedness" of sets in topology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polynomials/trigonometric functions/etc. can't be conservative, only vector fields can. Vector fields involving nice functions may or may not be conservative. It definitely isn't the case that these vector fields are usually conservative (as a side note, I don't know if "most vector fields are not conservative" is true in a mathematically precise sense). If we have $v = f(x,y)dx+ g(x,y)dy$, then at the very least, in order for $v$ to be conservative, we must have $f_y=g_x$, which usually isn't the case. For example, I just randomly came up with the example $v = (2x-2y)dx+(4x^2y^2)dy$, which is not conservative.

As for your second question. A vector field being conservative always means that its curl is zero. However, the converse does not always hold. For example, consider
$$v(x,y,z) = \frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}dx+\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}dy$$
You can verify that its curl is zero, but the integral around the unit circle on the $x-y$ plane will yield $\pm2\pi$. On the bright side, having zero curl does imply a vector field is conservative when the domain of the vector field is simply connected (meaning that if you take any loop on the domain, then you can shrink it to a point without leaving the domain). In the above example, the domain of $v$ is $\mathbb{R}^3$ minus the $z$ axis. If you have a loop around the $z$ axis, it cannot be shrunk to a point, and so the domain is not simply connected.

If I recall correctly, the simple connectedness condition can actually be weakened to requiring that the abelianization of the fundamental group of the domain not have elements of infinite order.

Comment: Cheers! In the "in order for $v$ to be conservative, we must have $f_y = g_x$ part, aren't you saying that for $v$ to be conservative, its curl ($f_y - g_x$) = 0? Or are you saying that IF that condition is violated, we mustn't have a conservative field (which means this is a good way to test it).

Comment: Those two statements are equivalent.

Comment: Isn't the first part saying basically if the curl is zero, $v$ is conservative (which isn't true as you wrote)

Comment: No, it's saying the converse of that: that if $v$ is conservative, then the curl of $v$ is zero.

Comment: I see. Thanks!  
Also in: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1322648/quickest-way-to-determine-if-a-vector-field-is-conservative  
The top answer was that the condition is an if and only if statement on $\mathbb{R}^3$. I'm afraid I might not be understanding your explanation on "simply connected". Does this have anything to do with a path-connectedness of a subset of R^3?

Comment: The wikipedia page for "Simply connected space" has a good illustration/discussion of what I mean. Say you take a loop, and you try to shrink it until it becomes just a point. If you can do this with any loop, then the set is simply connected. Intuitively, a set is simply connected if it has no holes, although some kinds of holes are okay. Simple connectedness doesn't have much to do with path connectedness, other than the fact that by some conventions simply connected spaces are required to be path connected.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure if my lecturer has mentioned anything about simple connected-ness and its relationship with conservative vector fields. Is it safe to say that R^n for any n is simply connected (assuming no points are taken out) (I think the article implies that, since it says any convex subset of R^n is simply connected) and so the curl condition is an if and only if?

Comment: Yep, that's true.